# Update cv::imshow() window using sigc::signal<void, cv::Mat> signal at run time

Tags: c++, opencv

There are lots of examples to show the live images in a cv::imshow() window, but all have a `while` loop with cv::waitKey() to control the update frequency.

I have a realtime image stream and whenever a new frame comes, it will send a `sigc::signal< void, cv::Mat >` signal. So I tried to write the callback function like this:

```
void myCallBack (cv::Mat inputImg)
{
    cv::imshow( "image", inputImg );
    std::cout<<"got a new frame"<<std::endl;
}
```

And I expect I should see the dynamic images in the imshow window. But the result is, the output text "got a new frame" is updating all the time in the terminal while I can only get a static image in the imshow window.

Is my idea wrong?

Comment: How are you binding the function to the event?

Comment: Thank you for comment. The myCallBack() function above is a member function of a Class FrmMain, the connection is defined in the constructor of the FrmMain: frmObserPtr->cvImageRceived().connect(sigc::mem_fun (*this,&FrmMain::myCallBack));  frmObserPtr is a pointer pointing to the object which emits the signal. cvImageRceived() is a getter of the signal. It's a little complicated to explain, but as I wrote, I can get the output from cout normally, can I assume that the connection has no problem? @Zindarod

Comment: The question is not if your callback function is being invoked or not. The question is if the `retrieve and grab` functions are writing to the `cv::Mat inputImg`. Without a minimal working code sample, it's impossible to tell. Also calling `imshow` inside the callback function is bad practice.